# Drupal 8 Twig User ID?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal & Twig and all I need is in my custom theme a twig expression to output the current user's ID. I can't find anything in the template comments, only if a user is logged in true / false.

Is there a simple way to get the ID of the current user? I'm not sure how to implement custom methods in a theme.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hello [bobomoreno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007594/bobomoreno),

I would suggest you use the module [Bamboo Twig](https://www.drupal.org/project/bamboo_twig).
The **Bamboo Twig** module provides some Twig extensions with some useful functions and filters aimed to improve the development experience.

You could then enable the sub-module `Bamboo Twig - Loaders`:

```
drush en bamboo_twig_loader -y
```

Finally, you will be able to use the Twig function `bamboo_load_currentuser`:

```
<!-- Get Current User -->
{% set user = bamboo_load_currentuser() %}
<div>{{ user.name.value }}</div>
<div>{{ user.uid.value }}</div>
```

You can find the [complete official documentation there](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/bamboo-twig/usage).

Answer (score 3):

In your theme find file yourthemename.theme and add following code:

```
function yourthemename_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
  $vars['uid'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
}
```

now if you edit your twig template for html, page, region, block, field, form element... you can use 'uid' token in your twig. It works for all hooks

Comment: It's quite "dangerous" and "time-consuming/performance" as you will set the `uid` value for Twig files of every template file (and you may not need it everywhere). Also, you could have issues with caching. I'm not sure I would recommend this approach as it impact the whole website.

Comment: Kevin why it is dangerous? Why time-consuming? Why I have a caching issue? It is a passing a variable to the function. Nothing more. Everybody who using drupal knowns how to use preprocess hooks works and how to use it for preprocessing a specific element.

Comment: Time-consuming as hooks are not very good for performances (especially the theme_preprocess which occurs on every template). Dangerous as you will have the short & pretty commonly named uid variable in every template. Caching issue depending of your cache tags/contexts & policies, the preprocess will not be reinterpreted by user (and so the uid value will be an incorrect one). I would be glad to discuss all of this in the Drupal Slack if you want (@wengerk).

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the ID in *user.html.twig*, it's `{{ user.id }}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how D8 now works, in two lines of executable code:

```
<?php
// This code returns the current user ID.
$account = \Drupal::currentUser();
return $account->id();
```

Answer (score 0):

The display name is not a field you can configure in {{ content }}. You can get it directly from the user entity:

```
{{ user.displayname }}
```

Reference for the php method: AccountInterface::getDisplayName

Answer (score 0):

The [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module is very small and yet very powerful. You can get the current user id with `drupal_token('current-user:uid')` I am using it to pass the current user id to a view like this:

```
{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'embed_1', drupal_token('current-user:uid')) }}
```